# Symfony misd phone number bundle how to provide existing phone

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I am using the great bundle https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle to store and retrieve phone number, but I have a problem when I want to pre-fill a form with it (not the same entity).

I have the following code in my Type

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Form\Type\PhoneNumberType;

class CreateAdType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tokenStorage;


    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }


    //Builds the form
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //Defines data
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $userEmail = is_object($user) ? $user->getEmail() : '';
        $userPhone = is_object($user) ? $user->getPhone() : '';

        //Defines fields
        $builder
            ->add('phone', PhoneNumberType::class, array(
                'label' => 'label.phone',
                'disabled' => $disabled,
                'widget' => PhoneNumberType::WIDGET_COUNTRY_CHOICE,
                'country_choices' => array(
                    'FR',
                ),
                ))
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                'label' => 'label.email',
                'disabled' => $disabled,
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'placeholder.email',
                    'value' => $userEmail,
                )))
            ;
    }


    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view['phone']->children['number']->vars['data'] = '123456789';
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Ad',
        ));
    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                // a unique key to help generate the secret token
                'intention' => 'createAdForm',
            ));
        }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'createAd';
    }

}
```

The resulting html code is the following

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <div>
        <div id="create_ad_phone" value="**THE_VALUE_APPEARS_HERE**">
            <select id="create_ad_phone_country" name="create_ad[phone][country]">
                <option value="FR" >France (+33)</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" id="create_ad_phone_number" name="create_ad[phone][number]" value="**BUT_I_NEED_THE_VALUE_HERE**" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This sets the value to the phone div, but not to the input phone_number, where I need it. Is there a way ?

Comment: You probably need to show more information for anyone to help you. What html code are you seeing, and what are you expecting?

Comment: I have added the resulting html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following in your form type, don't forget to `use`

```
...
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
...

    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view['phone']->children['number']->vars['value'] = $view['phone']->children['number']->vars['value'] ? $view['phone']->children['number']->vars['value'] : '+13008228232';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the function finishView() supposed to be called automatically ? As I can't see any differences

Comment: Yes it will be called automatically by symfony

Comment: So I've checked and if I dump the view after having assigned the number, I can see it but it does not display in the input and it does not even appear anywhere in the html code.

Comment: please show me your complete code for the form and what version of the bundle are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've updated the code in the question, not giving all the fields, but all the functions. And the version of the bundle is v1.1.2

Comment: And also, how do you pass the $userPhone from builder to finishView ?

Comment: I have updated the answer, it should replace by handleRequest

Comment: Thanks a lot! With "value" it worked well! But how can I passthe value from builder to finishView ?

Comment: `$view['phone']->children['number']->vars['value']` you can use same to put if condition to see if exist, else overwrite.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but I haven't understood. I have  tried to use the tokenstorage from constructor in finishView, but if I use getPhone() I also have the country code...

Comment: do `vardump($view['phone'])` this will give you overview of the object method. there should be number and country.. which you can change just like we changed for number.  check my answer again

Comment: Thanks! So I've managed it by using "getNationalNumber()" on the phoneNumber object issuing from my tokenStorage.

Answer (score 1):

In you method add you can use choices for select

```
         $builder
            ->add('phone', PhoneNumberType::class, array(
                'widget' => PhoneNumberType::WIDGET_COUNTRY_CHOICE,
                'country_choices' => array(
                    'FR',
                ),
                'choices' => array('number' => $user->getPhone))
            );
```

Comment: Thanks, it's really a good idea also, but it says that "The option "choices" does not exist."...

Comment: I just saw in the bundle , there is no "choices" . But what you can do is to overload his FormType and create your choices and set the value you see?

Comment: Yes I see, but it looks quite complicated

Answer (score 0):

Are you rendering in twig template?
If so have you tried passing in "$user" object to twig template from controller, and then call the "getPhone" function in twig.

Like so, in your controller:

```
return $this->render('default/some_template.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user'  => $user,
));
```

Then in your twig template somewhere:

```
{{ form_widget(form.phone, {'value' : user.getPhone}) }}
```

Try something like that to see if it works.
I haven't tried this - but it might work.